# Concatenate 2 elements of same vector and put it in another vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> data;

data[0] = 1;
data[1] = 1;
data[2] = 0;
data[3] = 1;
data[4] = 0;
data[5] = 2;
data[6] = 0;
data[7] = 2;
data[8] = 1;
data[9] = 2;
data[10] = 1;
data[11] = 2;
```

Now I want to arrange it in pairs, like  11 01 02 02 12 12.

i.e.

```
paired_data[0] = data[0]data[1]
paired_data[1] = data[2]data[3] etc....

paired_data[0] = 11;
paired_data[1] = 01;
paired_data[2] = 02;
paired_data[3] = 02;
paired_data[4] = 12;
paired_data[5] = 12;
```

I think concatenating vectors will work out here, but I am not sure how. Can someone suggest me to handle this with vector concatenation (or any other logic)?

If the data were of type `bool` then it would be easy to handle with left/right shifts. But `data` contain ternary data(0,1,2), so how can I handle that?

Comment: When you say you want it "in pair", do you mean that `1` and `1` should be eleven?

Comment: where did you get the input form? just use pair, simpler and work fine with vector

Comment: no... Its just one one not eleven. I am using this for some decoding process.

Comment: What do you intend if `data` has an odd number of elements?   That aside, consider what `10*data[i]+data[i+1]` gives you, for `i` equal to `0`, `2`, ....

Comment: use `vector < pair < unsigned int, unsigned int > >`

Comment: @AchmadJP : Input is given by observing some 2 signals. I can't get it in pairwise at that stage.

Comment: then used it after you get 2 input ^_^, i mean rather than collect them all first, you can just do it after 2 sequence right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to properly define "concatenation" operation. Do you mean bitwise concatenation or something complicated?

One approach is to use [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) template. This will provide you with concatenation of arbitrary types.
Another approach is to use multidimensional vector, i.e.

```
std::vector<int> data;
std::vector<std::array<int,2>> paired_data;
for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size() - 1; i+=2)
{
  paired_data.push_back(std::array<int,2>{{data[i], data[i+1]}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can easy convert it and contatenate this way, but iam not sure what u want

```
vector<unsigned int> data; // vector
unsigned int a = 4;
unsigned int b = 5;
data.push_back(a);      //push in vector
data.push_back(b);
int count=0;

    ostringstream oss; //convert
    oss << a << b;             //concatenate
    istringstream iss(oss.str());
    int c;
    iss >> c;  //  convert to int
    vector<unsigned int >paired_data;
    paired_data.push_back(c);


try to put this in a loop where u concatenate always two loop interations
```